# CronJob to copy a directory on a remote server

Tags: ssh, cron, ftp

I Need to create a Cronb that will run daily on my server and will ftp into a remote server with a username and password. It will copy a directory on that server and copy it onto a directory on my server. I then want the files to be deleted on the remote server.

Can someone help me with doing this?

Comment: Let me add this all needs to be done via terminal

Answer (score 1):

Use following command to edit your cron job:

```
crontab -e
```

Then add following to the end of that:

```
0 0 * * * lftp -u username,password -e "your command;quit" ftp.site.com
```

Obviously you must install [lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru/) package beforehand.

Comment: is lftp my only option?

Answer (score 1):

Use `crontab -e` to open your crontab file. Then add:

```
0 3 * * * rsync -raz --remove-source-files 'user:password@remotehost:/directory/to/copy' '/local/destination/directory/'
```

This tells cron to run this command every day at 3 AM. Adjust the first 5 parameters (`0 3 * * *`) as necessary to adjust the time when this runs and how often it runs

The rsync command does the following:

1. `-r`: recursively, i.e. get everything in the source directory and in directories under it
2. `-a`: archive, i.e. keep as much as the source information about the file as possible
3. `-z`: compress the data on the source before sending it
4. `--remove-source-files`: Remove the files on the source system (the remote system in this case) once complete

Comment: "--remove-soruce-files" is this where i want the files copied

Comment: No, that's `/local/destination/directory` at the end

Comment: its giving me Bash: !@(IP): event not found

Comment: All source args must come from the same machine.
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1)

Comment: You probably have an `!` at the end of your password. See my edit adding single quotes to the user:password@host bit

Comment: now its picking up the user as the hostname...

Comment: rsync -raz --remove-source-files '*******:*********@173.203.***.***:/s*********/En**********' '/mnt/En***********'

Comment: I'm not really sure what the issue is. Try changing your password to something simple to test it. The command should be working, but special characters in your password could throw it off

Comment: root@reports:~# rsync -raz --remove-source-files apple:test123@173.203.**.***:/apple/file /mnt/file
ssh: Could not resolve hostname apple: Name or service not known
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(605) [Receiver=3.0.9]

Comment: is calling the user as the hostname... hmm :/